# More ways to say "In his druken state"

Tags: phrase-requests

As I need to use the phrase a lot in a piece of document, I don't want to sound too repetitive ... so anyone with any suggestions as to alternative phrases and/or any phrases that suggest that someone is totally out of control (because of drunkenness)? Thanks!

Comment: No lists, as they are off topic. Please ask one authoritatively answerable question at a time and check out the [help] for more information on how to ask questions.

Comment: There isn't a lot of reason to avoid using the same phrase repetitively if it means what you need it to mean.

Answer (score 1):

Inebriated.  Defined as; drunk, intoxicated, stupefied or excited by a chemical substance (especially alcohol).

"He was helplessly inebriated after drinking the bottle of vodka."

Comment: This post would be improved if it included a reference and an explanation of why it answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no shortage of terms for being intoxicated.

[This link](http://sesquiotic.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/365-words-for-drunk/) provides some 365 different options.  Below are the English language options.

In his (choose one of the following 100s) state.

*The following will exemplify why lists are considered of topic.*

> addled
>   ankled
>   badgered
>   banjaxed
>   bashed
>   battered
>   beery
>   befuddled
>   befuggered
>   bent
>   besotted
>   bevvied up
>   bibacious
>   bibulous
>   blacked out
>   bladdered
>   blasted
>   blathered
>   bleezin
>   blitzed
>   blootered
>   blotto
>   boiled as an owl
>   bombed
>   boogaloo
>   boozed up
>   boozy
>   bosko absoluto
>   bosky
>   Brahms and Liszt
>   buckled
>   buttered
>   buttoned
>   buzzed
>   cabbaged
>   canned
>   Chevy Chased
>   clobbered
>   cockeyed
>   corned
>   crapulous
>   crocked
>   crunk
>   crunkered
>   dead to the world
>   decimated
>   destroyed
>   dipso
>   disorderly
>   drunk
>   elevated
>   etched
>   euphoric
>   fecked
>   feeling no pain
>   fleein’
>   fleemered
>   floothered
>   flushed
>   four to the floor
>   fried
>   fuddled
>   full as a goog
>   full of loud mouth soup
>   **full-snooted**
>   ganted
>   gassed
>   gatted
>   giddy
>   glorious
>   goosed
>   got yer wobbly boots on
>   got your beer goggles on
>   groggy
>   gubbed
>   guttered
>   had a bit too much
>   had one too many
>   half cut
>   half in the bag
>   half-crocked
>   half-seas over
>   hammer-blowed
>   hammered
>   hanging
>   have had too much to drink
>   have tied one on
>   having a close look at the footpath
>   having a jag on
>   having the whirlygigs
>   high
>   higher than a kite
>   hooched up
>   hosed
>   housed
>   howling
>   hunting bear with a swtich
>   in a stupor
>   in quite a state
>   in your cups
>   inabstinent
>   inebriated
>   inebrious
>   intemperate
>   intoxicated
>   jober as a sudge
>   jolly
>   juiced
>   kippered
>   lagged up
>   lamped
>   langered
>   larrupt
>   lashed
>   leathered
>   legless
>   liquidly exuberant
>   liquored up
>   liquorish
>   lit
>   lit like a Christmas tree
>   lit up
>   loaded
>   locked
>   loo la
>   looped
>   lubricated
>   luchy
>   lush
>   mad wey it
>   mangled
>   manky
>   mashed
>   maudlin
>   meff’d
>   mellow
>   Merle Haggard
>   merry
>   minced
>   ming mong
>   minging
>   moired
>   moist and garrulous
>   mollo
>   monged
>   monkey-full
>   mottled
>   Moulin Rouged
>   muckibus
>   muddled
>   mullered
>   muntit
>   muzzy
>   narcotized
>   Newcastled
>   nicely irrigated with horizontal lubricant
>   obfuscated
>   obliterated
>   obliviated
>   oblonctorated
>   off the wagon
>   off yer face
>   off yer pickle
>   off yer trolley
>   off your woo
>   on a bender
>   on a campaign
>   on a spree
>   on the turps
>   one over the eight
>   out cold
>   out of control
>   out of it
>   out yer tree
>   over the limit
>   overcome
>   overdosed on laughing syrup
>   paggered
>   palintoshed
>   paralytic
>   paralyzed
>   peelywally
>   peevied
>   phalanxed
>   pickled
>   pie-eyed
>   pished
>   pissed
>   piss-eyed
>   pixilated
>   plastered
>   plotzed
>   plowed
>   poleaxed
>   pollatic
>   polluted
>   potted
>   potulent
>   pot-valiant
>   predicting earthquakes
>   primed
>   rat-arsed
>   rat-legged
>   ratted
>   ravaged
>   razzled
>   red in the nose
>   reek-ho
>   rendered
>   ripped
>   rip-roaring
>   roaring
>   rubbered
>   ruined
>   sauced
>   scattered
>   schlitzed
>   schnockered
>   schnooked
>   screwed
>   scuppered
>   scuttered
>   seeing double
>   sewed up
>   shickered
>   shitfaced
>   shithoused
>   skew-whiff
>   slagged
>   slaughtered
>   slizzard
>   slopped up
>   sloppy
>   sloshed
>   slozzled
>   smashed
>   snatered
>   snobbled
>   snockered
>   sodden
>   somewhat the worse for wear
>   sottish
>   soused
>   sozzled
>   spaced
>   spangled
>   spannered
>   spiffed
>   spifflicated
>   splashed
>   splattered
>   spongelled
>   squiffy
>   squished
>   steaming
>   steampigged
>   stewed
>   stiff
>   stinking
>   stinko
>   stoned
>   stonkin
>   stotious
>   swacked
>   tanked
>   tashered
>   temulent
>   three sheets to the wind
>   tiddley
>   tight
>   tipsy
>   tired and emotional
>   toasted
>   totalled
>   trashed
>   troattered
>   trollied
>   troubled
>   trousered
>   tweaked
>   twisted
>   twizzled
>   under the influence
>   under the table
>   under the weather
>   unsober
>   unsteady
>   vulcanized
>   warped
>   wasted
>   well lubricated
>   wellied
>   whaled
>   Williamed
>   winehoused
>   wiped out
>   wired
>   with the fairies
>   woofled
>   woozy
>   wrecked
>   zombied
>   zoned
>   zonked

- Term in bold graciously attributed to @Hotlicks

Comment: You forgot "had a snoot full".

Comment: As so the quest for the complete list continues.  Would you accept full-snooted as a succinct addition?

Comment: I needed more formal phrases but that list is pretty awesome

Comment: Is *tight* still used this way?

Comment: @CarSmack Can't say I've ever read/heard _tight_ used that way, but that is true of many of these terms; when is the last time you heard _pixelated_ refer to a drunk?

Answer (score 0):

There are several phrases that could convey the same as "drunken state". The best that occurs to me is: "**intoxicated with alcohol**".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the phrase "drunken stupor".

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stupor) has the following definitions for **stupor**:

> a condition in which someone is not able to think normally because of being drunk, drugged, tired, etc.
>
> a condition of greatly dulled or completely suspended sense or sensibility <a drunken stupor>

It gives the following example for *stupor*:

> He fell into a drunken stupor.